# Python regex to match numbers but ignore words that have numbers in them (i.e. N95 and 3D)

Tags: python, regex

I have multiline strings of varying length and content that needs to be stripped of numbers, but I need to leave in words that legitimately contain numbers.

For example, this totally made up string (notice the line breaks):

```
"3 3D Apple car 19.74 N95 8.0 -8.0 .1 7,000 1. table
AH4R99JKH
75"
```

should be the following after the regex is applied:

```
"3D Apple car N95 table AH4R99JKH"
```

I have made many attempts at regular expressions to identify "real" numbers, but have failed miserably.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: `re.sub(r'\b([+.,0-9-]+)\b', '', your_string)`? The `\b` will catch the beginning or end of a word (i.e. the border between whitespace and the number you're searching for), and the group just contains all characters that a number may contain.

Comment: Could you show your attempts?

Comment: Here is one that I had, but I was working in an online tester and didn't keep all the iterations:
(^|\s)(\d+\.?\d*)(\s|$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with.

```
your_string = """3 3D Apple car 19.74 N95 8.0 -8.0 .1 7,000 1. table
AH4R99JKH
75"""
result = ' '.join(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+[0-9A-Z]+|[0-9A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+', your_string))
#'[a-zA-Z]+[\w]+|[\w]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+' same regex but more compact
```

This will give you:

> 3D Apple car N95 table AH4R99JKH

Comment: This does exactly what I need.  I was so focused on identifying the numbers I wanted to remove, I never considered looking for what I wanted to keep.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list contain all letters and check with that

This code helps you to do that

```
letter = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
string = "3 3D Apple car 19.74 N95 8.0 -8.0 .1 7,000 1. table AH4R99JKH 75"
str_list = string.split()
last_t = ''
for item in str_list:
    check = False
    for i in item:
        if i in letter:
            check = True
    if check == True:
        last_t += f'{item} '
        
print(f"{last_t.strip()}")

#response => "3D Apple car N95 table AH4R99JKH"
```